# Why is one being subtracted from the length of this list?

Tags: python

i saw this code online and i need help figuring out what this does!

```
words = ["hello", "world", "spam", "eggs"]
counter = 0
max_index = len(words) - 1   

while counter <= max_index:
    word = words[counter]
    print(word + "!")
    counter = counter + 1
```

What does the -1 do in this code?

Comment: Python lists' indices start from zero. So, if you have four elements in a list, then the last index will be three. Thats why `- 1`

Comment: But this isn't idiomatic python as `for word in words: print(word+"!")` or even simply `print('\n'.join(word + '!' for word in words))` would do the same thing without `max_index` and `counter`.

Comment: @AChampion that's true but I think the OP isn't asking us to change the code. Just to explain it.

Comment: @timotree read the answering rules. It's perfectly fine to say "Don't do that, instead do this". But that is not even an answer, it's just a comment.

Comment: @MohammadYusufGhazi I'm not saying that the comment was breaking any rules. I'm just saying I don't think that that comment will help the OP.

Comment: @timotree I disagree. It definitely teaches him the difference between good pythonic code and not so pythonic code.

Comment: @MohammadYusufGhazi Okay. I also was tempted to add that to my answer but decided not to as it isn't actually relevant to the question.

Comment: @timotree You should have added it with good explanation. And in case it gets heavily downvoted eating up your reps then just simply delete it to recover the lost reps.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Your code was probably looking like this:

```
counter = 0
words =  ["hello", "world", "spam", "eggs"]
max_index = len(words) - 1
while counter <= max_index:
    word = words[counter]
    print(word + "!")
    counter = counter + 1
```

What the code does here, is that it types every word in the list with '!' sign at the end. You could improve it by the following:

```
for word in words:
    print(word + '!')
```

This does exactly the same thing, but now you are iterating over the words in the list directly without any unnecessary variables. And it does not have to be "for **word** in words", it can be "for **element** in iterable".

Comment: I understand that their is a for loop for this while loop, it was brought to my attention in the lesson, what i don't understand is the -1 in the for loop

Comment: I mean (while) loop

Comment: Indexing in Python starts with 0, which means that the index of the last element in a list of length 4 is actually 3 - thus, -1 for the max_index variable

Comment: So assigning max_index to len(words) made the list 0,1,2,3,4 instead of 0,1,2,3 so we subtracted 1 to remove max_index?

Comment: Can i get ur email?

Comment: @EdwinHenriquez

Comment: u only tagged me no words

Comment: You are iterating from 0 to max_index in your loop, so, without the -1 part you will have list indexes 0,1,2,3,4. This will raise an error since there is no element of index 4 in the list. By setting it to len(list) - 1 your iteration stops at 3. This is exactly what the **range(n)** command does - it iterates up to n-1.

Comment: Thank u! Can u email me edwincoding1001@gmail.com this way i can directly ask for help!?

Comment: @VanDarkholme I fail to see how your answer address the OP's question. He asked about a very specific part of his code. He didn't ask how his code could be improved. He wanted an explanation. And while you may have given him one in the comments, the answer should have addressed it first.

Answer (score 9):

Python list are zero indexed. This means that the first index in a list is accessed by `0` not `1`. In your code, the maximum index of the list is being calculated.

The `len()` builtin function returns the length of a list. But if you attempt to use the value returned by `len()`, Python will raise an `IndexError`:

```
>>> l = ["hello", "world", "spam", "eggs"]
>>> l[len(l)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    l[len(l)]
IndexError: list index out of range
>>>
```

Imagine a series of boxes, each one holding an element. Each box is label with the appropriate index on the top, and the count on the bottom:

```
    0           1          2          3
|---------||---------||---------||---------|
| "hello" || "world" ||  "spam" ||  "eggs" | 
|---------||---------||---------||---------|
    1           2          3          4
```

The *amount* of boxes is four. There are four boxes. But there is no fourth index, there is only a third index. Python starts counting the number of "boxes" in the list at the number one. But Python starts counting the *indexes* of each "box" at the number zero.

This means that the maximum index of a list(the biggest number you can put in the `[]`'s), will always be one less than the length of the list. So to get the maximum index of a list, you must subtract one from the length of the list:

```
>>> l = ["hello", "world", "spam", "eggs"]
>>> l[len(l) - 1] # subtract one and this will work
'eggs'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your program loops until `counter > max_index`.

- If `max_index == 4` (`len(words)`) then your program will try to set `word = words[4]` but will fail because there is nothing in `words` at index `4`.
- If `max_index == 3` (`len(words) - 1`) then your program will never reach `counter == 4` and your program will work fine.